# Preprocess taxonomy for a custom template file

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming

In Drupal 6, I am customizing a view where I am trying to make the taxonomy terms work in all the page template files.

This is the code in the template.php file.

```
function getTermsName($taxonomy_id) {
  $terms = taxonomy_get_term($taxonomy_id);
  return $terms->name;
}
```

This is the code in the custom page template file.

```
$taxonomy_id = 'term id you got';
echo getTermsName($taxonomy_id);
```

Nothing happens.

I am quite bad at this; I hope in a very simple solution.

EDIT

With Boriana we found out that the mythemename_preprocess function is *not* working *not* taking effect in my drupal. If anyone has idea why, that will be the key to this problem.

Comment: My original question got edited due to grammar mistakes, though the code has been edited as well. As of the edit, it still does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use this in your page template files, then you should put your template.php code inside the **yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars)** function.  That's the one that will get called before your page template file, and it can "communicate" its results to the template file by putting them in the $vars variable which was passed to it by reference.

So here's an idea of how you can improve your code:

In template.php:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $term = taxonomy_get_term($taxonomy_id);
  $vars['term_name'] = $terms->name;     // Store anything you want to use later in $vars
}
```

In page.tpl:

```
<?php print $term_name; ?>
```

Let me know if that helps you get closer!

============================ EDIT =============

The variables set in the hook_preprocess_page() function are only available in your page.tpl files.  If you're trying to get to these variables in your view templates, you'll have to instead use a views pre-processing function, such as **mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars)**

Comment: I get this error in my apache log:[Tue Jul 10 19:09:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/web/sites/all/themes/htc/template.php on line 78

Comment: So it's not finding the $term_name variable that you set in this line: "$vars['term_name'] $terms->name;"... Did you change the 'mytheme' part in the function to your theme name?  You may not have realized that the pre-processing functions that to start with your theme name, and that was just a placeholder text for me...

Comment: I didi. It reads htc_preprocess_page(... .htc is my theme name.

Comment: I just edited my response to include some extra troubleshooting tips...

Comment: Based on example code I think the error in your previous code was missing the "=" from $vars['term_name'] $terms->name; so I changed it to: $vars['term_name'] = $terms->name; Now I get no error, but the problem is _it does not echo_ anything under $term_name. I tried with the test code and its not printing $test NOR printing "TESTING" anywhere.

Comment: Ah yes!  Glad I added that extra bit then.  ;-)  So it works now, right?

Comment: The only other thing I have in the preprocess is this: The only other thing I have in the htc_preprocess_page is // Page change based on node->type
  // Add a new page-TYPE template to the list of templates used
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    // Add template naming suggestion. It should alway use hyphens.
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-'. str_replace('_', '-', $vars['node']->type);    
  } But I don't think this should interfere...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4086/discussion-between-gergely-csata-and-boriana)

Comment: If it's not printing out the 'TESTING' string from the line I suggested "drupal_set_message("TESTING");", that means it's not going in the pre-processing function.  If it were going in there, it'd print that out.  So then that would be why your variable isn't getting set.  Make sure you have no typos in declaring the function and that all the arguments are correct and that it's using your theme name exactly as it should.  Try the following definition for the function, for example: function htc_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) with that extra parameter or look online for other clues...